# Modulus of normal random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, absolute-value

P and Q are variables such that-
$$P(P ≤ p,Q ≤ q)= \int_{-\infty}^{p} \int_{-\infty}^{q} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{\left[ -\frac{1}{2}{(g^2 + h^2)} \right]}dgdh$$

Now random variables $V = mod(P)$ and $C = mod(Q)$. 
How do I prove that they are independent?

Comment: Yes from the joint pdf it is easy to recognize that $W_1, W_2$ are independent. Then for any* function $g, h$, $g(W_1)$ and $h(W_2)$ are also independent.

Comment: What do you normally do to derive the  CDF of a function of a random variable?

Answer (score 4):

You already have an answer for the independence part. I'll give an answer for the distribution part. You can easily see that $W_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. I'll just write
 $W$. Let $x\geq 0$:
\begin{align} 
P(|W|\leq x)= P(-x \leq W\leq x)  = \Phi(x) - \Phi(-x) 
\end{align} 
Where $\Phi(\cdot) $ is the CDF of the standard normal. And surely $P(|W|\leq x) =0$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard result in probability theory that whenever $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ for (measurable) functions $f$ and $g$. This yields independence directly.

For the distribution you need to apply the transformation formula for densities. This would be just some computational work.

Comment: So I don't need to prove that the functions are independent? Can I  just directly state it?

Comment: @Dross Yes you can

Answer (score 0):

The part about independence has been answered (see a comment and the answers).

As far as the joint distribution of the absolute values
$$P(Z_1 ≤ z_1,Z_2 ≤ z_2)= P(-z_1\leq W_1 ≤ z_1,-w_2\leq W_2 ≤ z_2)= $$
$$=\int_{-w_1}^{w_1} \int_{-w_2}^{w_2} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{\left[ -\frac{1}{2}{(x^2 + y^2)} \right]}dxdy=\int_{-w_1}^{w_1}\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{ -\frac{1}{2}{x^2 } }\ dx\int_{-w_1}^{w_1}\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{ -\frac{1}{2}{y^2} }\ dy=$$
$$=(2\Phi(w_1)-1)(2\Phi(w_2)-1)$$
for positive $w_i$s -- otherwise zero. $\Phi$ is the distribution function of the standard normal case.

Note that the argumentation above  does not use independence directly. The latter simply follows from the shape of the  the original joint distribution.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind separating out the integrals? We used the fact that they are independent here, right?

Comment: No I did not use independence. I separated $e^{a+b}$ as $e^a e^b$  where $a $ depended only on $x $ an $b $ depended only on $y $ so the double integral bebame a product of to   simpler integrals.